# sql statement mysql notcorrect

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(m.own,3,4) as c , (select  amphur.AMPHUR_NAME where c = SUBSTRING(m.own,3,4)  ),
         COUNT(* ) AS cnt 
    FROM MEMBER AS m 

   GROUP BY SUBSTRING(m.own,3,4)
order by cnt desc
```

sql statement mysql
what wrong with code below when i fill

```
(select  amphur.AMPHUR_NAME where c = SUBSTRING(m.own,3,4)  )
```

it error

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (
  `idmember` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `own` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ssurname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sex` enum('¿','¿') NOT NULL,
  `Hno` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Moo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tambol` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `dateofbirth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `migratedate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('5','4','3','2','1') DEFAULT '5',
  `Unit` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `staff1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `staff2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fathercode` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `mathercode` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idmember`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8994 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amphur` (
  `AMPHUR_ID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AMPHUR_CODE` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `AMPHUR_NAME` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `GEO_ID` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PROVINCE_ID` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `province_name` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AMPHUR_ID`),
  KEY `province_name` (`province_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=999 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use aliases in the same level.

Even if you could, you are filtering on non-correlated columns in your subquery: the subquery would just return the record from `amphur` if there is one record, or an error if there are more.

Could you please provide some sample data and the desired recordset?

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery is missing a From clause:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(m.own,3,4) as c 
    , (select amphur.AMPHUR_NAME 
        From amphur
        Where ??? = SUBSTRING(m.own,3,4) )
    , COUNT(* ) AS cnt 
FROM MEMBER AS m
```

However, how does the `amphur` table relate to the `member` table?

Answer (score 0):

there is no "FROM" clause in your select Amphur.amphur_name